# Is there a way to use numeric font weight in CSS font shorthand?

Tags: css, fonts

Can I somehow use numeric font weight value (100-900) when I define a value of the font shorthand like `font: 12px 600 sans-serif` ?

Comment: Yes, according to the documentation you can: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/font - the order is font-family, font-size, font-stretch, font-style, font-variant, font-weight, line-height, so in your case its should be `sans-serif 12px 600`? Also, I just realised, but _you have it declared in your code_ anyway?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, it's possible, but it seems like, you must put the `bold` keyword before your `size` and then it will work.

If `font` is specified as a shorthand for several font-related properties, then; there are some rules as listed on [Mozilla docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/font).

- `font-style`, `font-variant` and `font-weight` must precede `font-size`.
- `font-variant` may only specify the values defined in CSS 2.1, that is
  `normal` and `small-caps`
- `font-stretch` may only be a single keyword value
- `line-height` must immediately follow font-size, preceded by "/", like
  this: `"16px/3"`
- `font-family` must be the last value specified.

```css
.a {
  font: 400 12px Georgia, serif;
}
.b {
  font: bold 12px Georgia, serif;
}
.c {
  font: 700 12px Georgia, serif;
}
```

```html
<p class="a">The font Property</p>
<p class="b">The font Property</p>
<p class="c">The font Property</p>
```